# Java execution stalled - Resolving model org.eclipse.recommenders:index::zip:0.0.0 31KB/1MB

Tags: java, eclipse

The code I'm executing is :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class NetConnectTest {
    public class DownloadTask {
        String download(String url) {
            String result = null;
            try {
                URL link = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) link.openConnection();
                con.connect();
                InputStream reader = con.getInputStream();
                for (int data = reader.read(); data != -1;)
                    result += (char) data;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String...args) {
        System.out.println("Starting Download...");
        DownloadTask dld = new NetConnectTest()
            .new DownloadTask();
        System.out.println(dld.download("https://www.somusysadmin.com"));
        System.out.println("Download Ended...");
    }
}
```

I'm using Eclipse oxygen 1a utilizing Java 9:

> > java -version
>
> java version "9.0.1"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)

The programs only generates the output:

> Starting Download...

But never prints the terminating statement. Further, the executing keeps on running. What am I doing wrong? The compiler doesn't generate any warnings/errors and neither do any exceptions occur. I don't think there's any infinite loops here. So, what's going on?

I checked the progress tab, and found the following progress bar not even moving an inch.

> Resolving model org.eclipse.recommenders:index::zip:0.0.0 31KB/1MB

Is it because of this that the program won't execute? If so, how do I resolve it?

**NOTE** : The processor usage and RAM usage both rise to 100% while eclipse is running - irrespective of whether the program is executing or has been stopped.

---

IDEOne produces a different output:

https://ideone.com/2avChN

Has anyone got any idea what's going on?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix your reading block like this:

```
int data = reader.read();
while(data != -1) {
    result += (char) data;
    data = reader.read();
}
reader.close();
```

Also set `String result` to empty string ("") not `null`.
Let's take a close look on your loop. You declaring `int data = reader.read();` and break condition. But `data` doesn't change through the  loop. This why you read some part of data and nothing happens further. It's indicated by *31KB/1MB*. In my implementation data is changing at every iteration. Actually you could do the same like this:

```
for(int data = fileReader.read(); data != -1; data = fileReader.read()) {
            result += (char) data;
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks!!

But how did the for loop turn into an infinite loop?!

Comment: basically, what was so wrong that needed to be fixed?!

Comment: @SomenathSinha The `int data = reader.read()` part of the `for` loop is only called at the beginning of the loop, so you never read again and `data` will never be -1

Comment: Whenever possible answers should explain what was wrong with the original code and well as providing corrected code.

Comment: @greg-449, I wasn't sure that it's the only problem cause I can't test it with his URL. But was sure that this part is wrong, that's why have answered shortly.